# excluding specific rows in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create a new dataframe selecting only those rows which a specific column value does not start with a capital S.
I have tried the following options:

```
New_dataframe = dataframe.loc[~dataframe.column.str.startswith(('S'))]

filter = dataframe['column'].astype(str).str.contains(r'^\S')
New_dataframe  = dataframe[~filter]
```

However both options return an empty dataframe. Does anybody have a better solution?

Comment: Can you test your first line of code with this setup please? `dataframe = pd.DataFrame({'ColA': ['Start', 'Hello', 'World', 'Stop'], 'ColB': [3, 4, 5, 6]})`

Answer (score 1):

Your code works well:

```
dataframe = pd.DataFrame({'ColA': ['Start', 'Hello', 'World', 'Stop'],
                          'ColB': [3, 4, 5, 6]})
New_dataframe = dataframe.loc[~df['ColA'].str.startswith('S')]
print(New_dataframe)
```

Output:

```
>>> New_dataframe
    ColA  ColB
1  Hello     4
2  World     5

>>> dataframe
    ColA  ColB
0  Start     3
1  Hello     4
2  World     5
3   Stop     6
```